# Q_oper8 with call back function in child to return data to mail process

Tags: node.js, callback

I am using Q_oper8 in node.js to runs jobs in a queue using a pool of processes .
It works fine if i return the data from actionMethod .But when I use any call back function to return data in actionMethod it  does not work.

Can any one help me out ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the library I found the solution.
you need to have 
actionMethod(action,fnReturnResponse) as childPrecess Handler.

And what ever you need to return , you can return from your callback function by calling 
fnReturnResponse(returnValue);

You will also need to pass second argument of childProcess handler  to be true (stands for isAsync)

childProcess.handler(actionMethod,true);